# Bind a simple Map<String, String> in a JAX-RS resource with Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS resource class, and for one of the methods, I'd like to bind a simple `Map<String, String>` representing the JSON `POST` to the server, rather than create an entity class for such a short request. I thought I could do the following:

```
@POST
public Response create(Map<String, String> json) {
    //business logic...
    return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromPath("{id}").build(id)).build();
}
```

but when I hit that endpoint with curl, I get a 415 Unsupported Media Type. Is there any way to allow for simple binding like this, or do I need actual annotated POJOs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to write your own `MessageBodyReader` to tell the framework how to convert json to a generic `Map`, you could still accept a `String` and use Jackson to read it as in:

```
@POST
public Response create(String json) {
    Map<String,Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class);
    //business logic...
    return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromPath("{id}").build(id)).build();
}
```

Comment: The actual problem was actually a configuration issue, but before I figured that out, your solution worked as an alternative, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: Well, thanks. Could you update the question with the config issue (an its solution)?